# Javascript - React Native Console error "Version Mismatch"

Tags: javascript, react-native, ios-simulator

Hello I am new to react native,
There are many answers regarding version issue but none of them work in my case.
Javascript version: 0.62.2 Native Version: 0.63.0.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
killall node -9
npm start
```

Try this